# Is it possible to make Notepad++ support Tamil language functionality?

Tags: notepad++, i18n

Notepad++ (from v2.3) supports the [multilanguage functionality](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) by means of a translated XML file (from `english.xml`). Normally you don't need it if you install Notepad++ by its installer. You may need the language file if you install Notepad++ from zip format binary (or if your language is not supported by NSIS installer.)

Is it possible to make Notepad++ support Tamil language functionality? If so, how to get started?

Comment: Hi your answers are really rocking and I have an doubt if we install notepad++ installer there is no need of XML file then why do we need zip or binary packages. Only for inputting purpose we need other languages then Microsoft Indic Language Input tool is enough know. Why do we go for XML files?.
sorry I don know whether i misunderstood or not this id the doubt that i actually got.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, make your own Tamil translation file by translating **english.xml** file. To do that, at first open the file in Notepad++, go to **Format** menu and select the option **Convert to UTF-8 without BOM**. Save the changes. Since Tamil is a Unicode language, this step is necessary. After that, change the value of **encoding** attribute on the first line to **UTF-8**. It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Now, follow the steps given [here](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/translation-HOWTO.php/"here") to translate the file into Tamil. The steps for using the translated file is also given on that page.
To input Tamil text, you can take the help of Microsoft Indic Language Input tool or  Google Transliteration IME for tamil. For translation, you can take the help of Google Translate, English to Tamil dictionary available on shabdkosh.com or even the Tamil LIP for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Tamil is well supported in [unicode - which can be used with xml](http://www.w3.org/TR/unicode-xml/) - you do not want to be using TSCII , so you'd probably have to [create your own translation file](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) (google transliterate is one good, universal tamil input tool).

Then send it to the author ;)